# Apache ProxyHTMLURLMap is adding my target URL twice

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-html

I'm not sure what's happening here.  But for some reason my returned URLs that come back from the actual server looking like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/adeaf892aebee1fafa6c473af5152fed-CDN/en_US-isej02/64024/83/37/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css" media="all">
```

End up with my proxy URL inserted twice, i.e.:

```
</script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/igurl/igurl/s/adeaf892aebee1fafa6c473af5152fed-CDN/en_US-isej02/64024/83/37/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css" media="all">
```

The relevant section of my httpd.conf looks like:

```
<Location /igurl>

    # Hard coded credentials
    AuthBasicFake blah blah

    ProxyHTMLLinks a href
    ProxyHTMLLinks area href
    ProxyHTMLLinks link href
    ProxyHTMLLinks img src longdesc usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks object classid codebase data usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks q cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks blockquote cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks ins cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks del cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks form action
    ProxyHTMLLinks input src usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks head profile
    ProxyHTMLLinks base href
    ProxyHTMLLinks script src for

    ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
        onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
        onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
        onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

    ProxyPass https://abc.def.com/
    ProxyPassReverse https://abc.def.com/

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /igurl/

</Location>
```

Any idea what I've done wrong here?  I can't see why this would match twice.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case this helps anyone.

Well, I've got it working with a bit of research - thanks to this article: http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Reverse_Proxy_Server:_mod_proxy_html

Not completely sure why, but this configuration works for me:

```
# Reverse Proxy to test out authentication

ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyPass /igurl/ https://abc.def.com/
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://abc.def.com /igurl
<Location /igurl/ >

    # Hard coded credentials
    AuthBasicFake blah blah

    ProxyHTMLLinks a href
    ProxyHTMLLinks area href
    ProxyHTMLLinks link href
    ProxyHTMLLinks img src longdesc usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks object classid codebase data usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks q cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks blockquote cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks ins cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks del cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks form action
    ProxyHTMLLinks input src usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks head profile
    ProxyHTMLLinks base href
    ProxyHTMLLinks script src for

    ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
        onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
        onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
        onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

    ProxyPassReverse https://abc.def.com/

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /igurl/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /igurl /igurl

</Location>
```